# Is it possible to write a file containing macros-gathered data at compile time?

Tags: rust

I have a couple of macro which collect signatures of some of my defined functions and then generate a function which can emit this data as `` &`static str ``.

E.g.

```rust
// stores 'test_fn1() -> u8' inside lazy_static variable
#[test_macro]
fn test_fn1() -> u8 {}


// stores 'test_fn2(u8) -> u8' inside the same lazy_static variable
#[test_macro]
fn test_fn2(arg1: u8) -> u8 {}


// generates a function 'get_signatures' that emits everything lazy_static variable has
generate_get_signatures!();
```

I want to output this data to some separate file during the same compilation process.
Is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to give some details on what you mean by "some parts of my program". The `built`-crate may also help.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, currently, technically possible for a macro to write a file. However:

1. The Rust compiler **does not guarantee that macros will be invoked in any order, or only once, or even at all** (e.g. in case of partially recompiling a modified crate) — [citation.](https://github.com/rust-lanxg/reference/issues/578) Therefore, you cannot rely on `generate_get_signatures` being able to see `test_macro`'s results.
2. [There is interest in executing proc macros inside a WebAssembly sandbox](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-procmacros-implemented-in-wasm/10860), for security and deterministic builds. If this were implemented, you would no longer even be able to write files.
3. [It is just not recommended for proc-macros to have side effects.](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9084)

Proc macros are supposed to be “pure functions” from input source code to output source code, independently at each macro call site. Don't use them to produce other outputs. Use `build.rs` if you need a complex code generation step.

If your problem is not to actually **generate a file** but to be able to discover all of the individual `#[test_macro]` annotated functions, then you may find [`inventory`](https://crates.io/crates/inventory) or [`linkme`](https://crates.io/crates/linkme) useful; they provide ways to access (at run time) information that is gathered from multiple sources in the code without needing to hardcode a centralized list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you suggest any other solution to achieve what I want? Basically, I need my program to emit some introspective info as a separate file. I'm new to Rust (came from Kotlin) - maybe there are some kind of compiler plugins for Rust to extend it's capabilities the mentioned way?

Comment: @AlexanderVtyurin I'm not familiar with what options there might be regarding extending the compiler (outside of proc-macros). However, if you don't absolutely need a *separate file*, but would be satisfied with the program being able to discover the information itself, then there are some options which I've edited my answer to mention.

Comment: Hey @KevinReid, it's been some time since your answer, which is pretty comprehensive, I appreciated the links especially. However I am in a similar shoe than the OP, I'd like to generate bindings for other languages for my API defined in rust. Build script could do the opposite, generate rust code from external files, but I need to generate external files from rust code. Any ideas?

Comment: @ÁkosVandra-Meyer You would be best off asking a new question, to get more eyes on it, as I haven't ever dealt with that myself. But note that you can use [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/) to parse Rust files from a regular program.